# HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors Error: Functions did not deploy properly. firebase-realtime-database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

```
exports.SentNotificationToCarServiceAppUserBasedOnWorkOrPaymentStatusUpdates =
    functions.database.ref('/carServiceNoti/{uid}/{pushid}')
        .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
            const original = snapshot.val();
            try {
                    if (original=== null ? false : true) {
                        //here i need to sent push notification
                        admin.database().ref("/noit/"+context.params.uid+"/"+context.params.pushid).push().set(original);
                         return 200; 
                    }else{
                        return 200;
                    }
                }catch(e){
                    return 200;
                }
            });
```

> HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors
>
> Error: Functions did not deploy properly.

Comment: Add more detail and scene what you are doing

Comment: after reduce method name length problem soved